# What services are required for Windows Media Player to share media?

Tags: services, windows-media-player

What services must be set to automatic or manual in order for the Media Sharing option in Windows Media Player to function?

I ask, because I've turned off some services, and I can't for the life of me figure out what one needs to be turned back on for this function to work again. When I try to setup sharing again, the dialog box hangs when I attempt to share my media under the Library Drop-down and "Media sharing ..." in WMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service, of course.

This link will also be helpful:
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/faq/sharing.mspx

It has information about how to set up your firewall, and mentions among other things that the IPSEC service must be turned off.

Comment: Well, I feel like a dumb ass, I did not read that and I really should of when I went through the list, but I had a case of "no-lookie-itis".